# What is the difference between importing sql database using "source" command vs. writing it in 1 line?

Tags: mysql, database, cmd

I can import a database like this:

`C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u {username} -p {databasename} < file_name.sql`

Or like this:
`C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u {username} -p`

`use databasename;`

`source file_name.sql;`

What is the difference between those 2 approaches? Is one preferred over the other? The first one seems to freze the cmd, the second is much more verbose in cmd, reporting every line giving a better feel for when it will finish. After all data was already imported cmd still reports performing some "tmp" table manipulations that I don't understand. Is there anything else to watch out?

Comment: it depends on what is inside the sql. The first approach is if the dump contains the database creation. the second if the database already exists and the dump is adding to the db